# How can I get a file and Seek through ipfs?

Tags: go, ipfs

I'm developing a specialised browser and part of that I would like to support the ipfs protocol. Thus this simple question:

- How can I get a file through the ipfs protocol using Go? The browser I'm building specialised in streaming media so I need an io.ReadSeeker.

What I've tried so far:
 I read the documentation... All I could find is the command line(which is useless to me as I'm considering a tighter integration/a Go API) and the [shell.Get method](https://godoc.org/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api#Shell.Get) which is undocumented and seems to require an "outdir" instead to return an io.ReadSeeker/ReadSeekCloser

Comment: Isn't the https://godoc.org/github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs-api#Shell.Cat what you want?

Comment: @ain Almost... I actually need to be able to seek as well so basically I need a ReadSeeker. I've just edited the question.

Comment: I don't think IPFS is seekable. I could be wrong, but I didn't see anything applicable from a few quick looks around.